# Atmega328p - PCB ISP pins for bootloader and sketch upload

Tags: atmega328, pcb-design

I want to design my PCB with Atmega328p chip on it and I want to be able to burn Bootloader and sketch after that while everything is soldered on the PCB. So my question is, what would be the best way to do that? My current idea is to leave extra pins for burning a Bootloader, and to leave also extra pins for uploading the sketch, and to "unplug" other stuff connected on these pins (for example on hardware UART) by adding\removing jumpers.

I'm pretty new to all this stuff, so I'm not quite sure what's the best approach.

Comment: If you're leaving pins (SPI pins, by the way) for uploading the bootloader, why bother with the bootloader at all - just program direct using those ISP pins.

Comment: I'm pretty new to arduino programming, I thought that I must have bootloader uploaded first and then to upload my sketch. I didn't know that I can upload sketch directly without bootloader...can I?

Comment: Yes, you can. The bootloader is purely for convenience so you don't need a hardware programmer. Since you already have the hardware programmer you don't need the convenience of the bootloader.

Comment: By hardware programmer, do you mean another arduino which I can connect to my board like when I'm burning an bootloader, or it can be done even just with FTDI cable?

Comment: Another Arduino, yes, or something more convenient like a USBASP ($2 on eBay from China), but not an FTDI cable, no.

Comment: Ok, that is excellent news! You just saved me some extra time and space for design traces on PCB :) One more think then, when I'm using that hardware programmer, do I need to change something in my sketch, or I'm still using it as it is, the code I mean?

Comment: The code is the same. Just select a different programmer in the IDE.

Comment: One further advantage: you don't get the 2 second delay at startup while pin 13 (LED) blinks as the bootloader times out. Your sketch starts instantly and you don't get strange things happening on pin 13.

Comment: And based on this http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Program-AVR-chip-using-a-USBASP-with-10-pin-cable.php I basically just need to leave 6 pins, that 4th pin says NC I guess as Not Connected, and there's few for GND which can be just one I guess. @Mayenko feel free to answer and I will accept it as a valid answer. You helped a lot to me today to understand few new things, thanks.

Comment: The ISP header is RESET, MOSI, MISO, SCK, GND and +5V.

Comment: That USBASP from what I see in description (ebay\aliexpress) looks like it's not for ATMEGA328P, it's for  ATMEGA8 ATMEGA128. Can I use if for ATMEGA328P as well?

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, you should design ATmega boards to support both ISP and bootloader pins.  The logic is simple:

- Unless you buy pre-programmed chips, or have a programming fixture, you will need ISP either to load the firmware itself, or to load a bootloader.
- Even if you plan to use only ISP for programming, it is still worth providing external connections to the UART pins for interacting with firmware during development; generally with ATmega-based Arduinos you do not have a breakpoint debugger, so debug messages on serial are your primary visibility into what is happening.
- You should wire the reset line to somewhere that you can manipulate it, so you don't have to power cycle your firmware every time you want to restart it in testing.

Once you have done all that, you end up with support for both ISP and UART bootloader - regardless if you plan to use them both or not.